# Call python from Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, cygwin

On my Matlab **R2016a**, the `py` object is not available. So I tried to  register my Python executable with `pyversion` as follow:

```
>> pyversion('C:/cygwin64/bin/ls.exe')
Error using pyversion
Cannot use  Python. Use 64-bit Python instead.

>> pyversion('C:/cygwin64/bin/python2.7.exe')
>> pyversion

       version: ''
    executable: ''
       library: ''
          home: ''
      isloaded: 0

>> py.os.sys.version
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
>> py.print('Hello World!')
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
```

A demonstrated it does not work.

How can I configure Python on my Matlab installation?